# What is the difference between delegated authentication and single sign-on (SSO)?

Tags: single-sign-on, delegated-authentication

On the [exam guide](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Salesforce-Certified-Identity-and-Access-Management-Designer-Exam-Guide) for Salesforce Certified Identity and Access Management Designer, it says that you should be able to

> Describe the configuration requirements of delegated authentication in Salesforce.

As I've been researching, SSO has been brought up quite a bit. There is obviously an overlap between delegated authentication and SSO. I get the impression the exam guide should say

> Describe the configuration requirements of delegated authentication *single sign-on (SSO)* in Salesforce.

Are delegated authentication and SSO the same thing? Can there ever be an instance when working with delegated authentication that you are not using SSO?

Comment: SSO is single sign on which can be implemented by various ways like Social sign on, SAML etc. Now by contacting salesforce this can be also implemented by using delegated authentication. Salesforce passes the username password and ip to the endpoint that you provide and helps to log in the user. So I would say those are not same thing. Delegated Authentication is one of the way of doing SSO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Delegated Authentication, the user logs in through the normal Salesforce login page, but Salesforce checks with a third-party server for the password. In this case, the user literally has no Salesforce password and cannot log in without the authentication server's permission.

```
         Delegated Authentication Flow
User -----> Salesforce Login 
                            -----> DA Server
                            <----- Assertion
     <----- Salesforce Session
```

With SSO, the user logs in through an Identity Provider (**not** the Salesforce login page), and the user is given an "assertion" that Salesforce uses to log the user in. In this case, the user has a Salesforce password (though they may be unaware of what it is), and can conceptually log in directly to Salesforce without this assertion.

```
         SSO Login Flow
     User -----> Salesforce Login
          <----- Redirect to IdP
      --- Steps above are optional ---
          -----> IdP Server
          <----- Assertion
          -----> Salesforce Login
          <----- Salesforce Session
```

---

Delegated Authentication isn't SSO, it's simply a way for an organization to control the user's password policies. The main difference is that with SSO, the user still has a Salesforce password that can be reset, etc, while with DA, the user doesn't have a Salesforce password, and if they attempt to reset the password, will be told to contact their network administrator.

In Salesforce, when you talk about SSO, you're talking about JWT- or SAML-based login mechanisms. When you talk about DA, you're talking about a single specific technology where the user no longer has a password in Salesforce and cannot login without the authentication server.

As the steps above attempt to demonstrate, the browser may be involved in several steps of SSO, while with Delegated Authentication, Salesforce does all the work and the user may never realize a third-party server was involved in the authentication.

---

> Are delegated authentication and SSO the same thing?

No.

> Can there ever be an instance when working with delegated authentication that you are not using SSO?

They are literally different things, so yes, every instance of DA will not be an instance of SSO, as far as they're defined.

Comment: are you aware of any Salesforce docs that talk about configuring DA without SSO? Everything I've found includes SSO. I guess Login Flows can purely use DA without SSO?

Comment: @TylerZika DA differs from the normal SSO in that (a) it must be enabled by Salesforce, (b) the login server calls the web service, (c) DA-enabled users can't reset their Salesforce passwords, and (d) the DA server requires custom coding. I see now the docs do sometimes call it DA SSO, but it's a totally different beast. DA could be set up to use RSA tokens, Google Authenticator, or whatever else, and need not be a traditional SSO.

Comment: thanks for the clarification and great responses!

Comment: it's confusing how in the config instructions it mentions SSO multiple times (Build your SSO web service, specify your org’s SSO gateway URL, Enable the Is Single Sign-On Enabled permission), but SSO isn't technically used, right? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_delauthentication_configuring.htm&type=5