# Users without 'Is Single Sign-On Enabled' checked flag are still able to log in via SSO

Tags: user, single-sign-on, user-management, login-errors

After thorough checking of users, I noticed that some of them, despite having no profile or permission set assigned with 'Is Single-Sign-On' flag enabled, are able to log in via SSO. What can be the problem? Does anyone know how this flag works?

Entries in the Login History for these users clearly state that they used the "SAML Sfdc Initiated SSO" login type.

Worth mentioning is that it works the same way for old and new users.

Comment: The permission is used to force SSO, here's a [good Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366958/can-saml-sso-be-selectively-enforced-for-a-group-of-users/). Its absence does not imply users cannot use SSO. Denying SSO to some users would be an odd choice but perhaps you have a use case for it. Please edit your question and clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Okay this solves my problem :) I didn't know that this flag is about ENFORCING the SSO, I thought that "enable" for salesforce also means ENABLEMENT. Thank you so much @identigral.